# How to cause ttk OptionMenu dropdown selection (expansion) on object focus via tab traversion?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, ttk

We have a Tkinter form with ttk OptionMenu dropdown boxes on it. When you click on the dropdown you can start typing your selection and the dropdown will automatically focus on the selection that starts with those characters.

The problem occurs when you use tab to traverse to the menu, rather than using the mouse. Tab will highlight the ttk.OptionMenu however it will not expand the dropdown to begin typing text unless you hit the spacebar or click.

Is there are way to force click() or something any time the OptionMenu gets tab focused?

I attempted to do some stuff with .bind and .configure but I'm definitely lost :)

```
   cust_selection = StringVar(window)
   customers = getcustomerlist() # pulls customer list from file
   vic_name_lbl = Label(window, text="Select Customer:")
   vic_name_lbl.grid(column=0, row=3)
   vic_name_box = ttk.OptionMenu(window, cust_selection, *customers)
   vic_name_box.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=(W,E))
   vic_name_box.configure(width=15)
```

Comment: Use the [`'<FocusIn>'`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) event: Keyboard focus was moved to this widget, or to a child of this widget.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful, but the documentation says that all `ttk` widgets have a `takefocus` attribute, which:

> Determines whether the window accepts the focus during keyboard
>   traversal. 0, 1 or an empty string is returned. If 0 is returned, it
>   means that the window should be skipped entirely during keyboard
>   traversal. If 1, it means that the window should receive the input
>   focus as long as it is viewable. And an empty string means that the
>   traversal scripts make the decision about whether or not to focus on
>   the window.